# How to open an html file in chrome app mode and make it default for use

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I am working on a web application in my Office to ease my work, I've used JQuery and HTML in my Application, due to security concerns I'am not able to install any third party software on machine and i want to use my html file in app mode so that it can give a app like experience. Is there any way to open my html in app mode so that other non tech savvy user can also use it easily.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the chrome developer tool(menu on the top right > more tools > developer tool).

One the top of the developer tool, click btn show in the image below.

[image: btn to show the mobile mode]

And the webpage will show as a mobile size.

[image: mobile mode]

Comment: Thanks, but i want an app like experience in desktop for this file only, other websites should work as usual.

Comment: you can open another tab to view other websites